# Node 'readline' module does not have an 'end' event - how can I do something when there are no more lines?

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

Reading [the official docs for the readline module](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html), there is no `end` event like other streams. 
Trying

```
reader.on('end', cb);
```

Doesn't work.

How can I run a callback once there are no more lines to be read?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Nevermind, it's `close`.

```
reader.on('close', cb);
```

Comment: The reader doesn't have but the `reader.input` I think does have an `end` event

Comment: Could you accept your answer since it is correct? 