# Read File and return count of certain lines

Tags: node.js

I am attempting to read a flat (text) file and return the number of lines that start with a "1" or a "2".

The issue i'm seeing is that the "recordCount" returns a 0.  Would like the recordCount variable to be incremented by 1 every time the condition is met.

```
export async function getReportRecordCount(finalFile: string, filePath: string) {
    try {
        let recordCount = 0;
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(`${filePath}/${finalFile}`),
            output: process.stdout
        });
        rl.on("line", (line) => {
            if (line.toString().startsWith("1" || "2")) {
                recordCount++;
            }
        });
        return recordCount;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Could you paste the sample of your file which you are passing as input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly promisify the `getReportRecordCount` function (right now, it's returning `recordCount` immediately, right after the interface is created, before any of the lines have been read. In order to listen for all lines to have finished being read, use the [`close`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22915816) event.

You also need to fix the `startsWith` logic - `("1" || "2")` evaluates to `"1"`. Use a regular expression instead.

```
export function getReportRecordCount(finalFile: string, filePath: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let recordCount = 0;
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(`${filePath}/${finalFile}`),
            output: process.stdout
        });
        rl.on("line", (line) => {
            if (/^[12]/.test(line.toString())) {
                recordCount++;
            }
        });
        r1.on("error", reject);
        r1.on("close", () => resolve(recordCount));
    });
}
```

Once it becomes more stable, I'd suggest using [`readline`'s Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readlinepromisescreateinterfaceoptions) instead of manually constructing the Promise.